# How to flip image vertically in blender without dealing with UV?

Tags: image, textures, blender, flip

I'm writing the script which imports model save in custom format. Textures are saved as vertically flipped DDS, so when i open this textures in Blender, the mapping doesn't look good. Is there any way to flip the image vertically without changing UV coordinates?

P.S. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Using blender internal you can set the image mapping scale to `-1`

[image: image mapping]

In python you can set that with `material.texture_slots['Texture'].scale = (-1,-1,-1)` note that it is a [texture slot](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MaterialTextureSlot.html) property not a texture property.

In cycles you do the same thing with a texture mapping node.

[image: texture mapping node]

Using python you can set the [mapping node](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.TexMapping.html) properties `map_node.scale = (-1,-1,-1)`

Comment: I used the first method and my texture is still not flipped. Maybe i must do something more after that?

Comment: Did you get the correct texture slot? Does it work if you change the setting manually?

Comment: It doesn't work even if i changing that manually. I am sure i got correct texture slot.

Comment: Have you any ideas?

Comment: Without running your script myself to see what it is doing I can't think of something else.